# DT State-Space State Feedback Control

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

Suppose we are given the following discrete-time system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k+1)\\
x_2(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 && 1\\
-2 && 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k)\\
x_2(k)
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}u(k)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 && 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{equation}

For this system we can construct a state feedback in the form

$$u(k) = v(k) + \begin{bmatrix}
k_1 && k_2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k)\\
x_2(k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

for which the system has a double pole at some $\beta$. I can design such a state feedback.

Now, suppose this desgined feedback can be active for one time step and the systems returns to its original form (no feedback) until the the next re-activation of the feedback.  This re-activation takes 2 time steps. I want to find the value $\beta$ to maintain the stability. I'm confused at this question since the stability is considered as $k$ goes $\infty$.

Comment: This will be a typical switched system with two subsystems. You may try to design a control law that stabilizes the system for any switching sequence, but that will be restrictive. Otherwise, you may consider certain dwell-time constraints and try to stabilize the system under those dwell-time constraints. Typical dwell-times are fixed, constant, minimum, persistent, and range dwell-times. There is an abundant literature on the topic.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the activation pattern of the controller?

Comment: @KBS, I'm not familiar with this concept. I studied state feedback and pole placement. Can you suggest a source (textbook) for switched systems?

Comment: Please answer the question regarding how the controller activates.

Comment: @KBS, Activation pattern repeats itself perdiodically of 3 time steps. 1 step with feedback and 2 steps with no feedback. Then repeat.

Comment: Ok, then this will be a periodic system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment, this is a periodic system that can be written as

$$x(3(k+1))=A^2(A+BK)x(3k).$$

Asymptotic stability is ensured provided that the eigenvalues of $A^2(A+BK)$ are inside the unit disc. A way to ensure that is through the consideration of a quadratic Lyapunov function of the form $V(x)=x^TPx$ where $P$ symmetric positive definite (i.e. $P\succ0$). This yields the following Linear Matrix Inequality

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-Q & A^3Q+A^2BU\\(A^3Q+A^2BU)^T & -Q
\end{bmatrix}\prec0$$

where $U$ and $Q\succ0)$ are matrices to be computed and the inequality sign means that the above expression is negative definite. A suitable gain $K$ can be constructed using the expression $K=UQ^{-1}$.

This can be slightly modified by considering a scalar $\beta\in(0,1)$ and solving for the condition

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\beta^2 Q & A^3Q+A^2BU\\(A^3Q+A^2BU)^T & -Q
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,$$

which is equivalent to saying that the spectral radius of $A^2(A+BK)$ is less than $\beta$.

A more direct approach (see Kwin's comment) is to just design a state-feedback controller for the system $(A^3,A^2B)$. It is interesting to note that this system may not be controllable even if $(A,B)$ is. A simple example is the integrator $\dot{x}=u$.

Comment: Lyapunov equation for discrete time systems is that there exists a positive definite $P$  which is the solution of the equation $A^TPA - P < 0$ for the exponential stability (or asy. stability for lti). I dont understand the the matrix you constructed (which is negative definite) in the answer. What's that?

Comment: @eet I considered the Lyapunov condition, performed a Schur complement, then a congruence transformation, and finally I used the change of variables to get a condition which is affine in both $Q$ and $U$.

Comment: One can also just use $(A^3,A^2B)$ instead of $(A,B)$ and design a state feedback gain $K$ for that, for example using pole placement. In that case one doesn't need to involve Lyapunov functions.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, this is correct. The thing is that I started to write a different answer for dwell-time switching and ended up writing this one. So, I kept the LMI formulation.

Comment: @KBS, If you can provide Kwin's approach when you have time, that would be very helpful since I'm not familiar with Schur complement approach.

Comment: @KBS, what is the value of $\beta$ to maintain the stability for the alternative approach then?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, since the alternative approach is yours, you can also comment if you want.

Comment: @eet the eigenvalues need to be in the unit disc to have stability.

Comment: @KBS, is it $|\beta| < 1$ then?

Comment: @eet you can easily figure this out by yourself. There is no need to ask such a question.